# How can I always remember the latest value from each sensor and write them into a file?

Tags: java, android-studio, runnable, sensors

I develop an android app for my final year project. This app must collect sensor smartphone information from accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer and to save them into a file. So far I have done everything, but now I have some problem with sampling rate frequency of sensors, I do not exactly know how to deal with that.

I tried to use runnable method to delay 10ms for accelerometer and gyroscope and other runnable method to delay 100ms for magnetometer. I did that because with approximation I guess that the values for ACC and GYR are changing every 10 ms. while for MAG this value is changing every 100 ms.

I have NEVER used this runnable method, I am a beginner. My code works, it creates the file, but it has 0 bytes, which means that my code is not entering properly into the RUNNABLE method. What should I change?

```
package localhost.dev.liverpoolsensorsfusion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RecordDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Sensor mGyroscope;
    private Sensor mMagnetometer;
    Handler handler10;
    Runnable runnable10;
    Handler handler100;
    Runnable runnable100;
    CheckBox checkAcc;
    CheckBox checkGyro;
    CheckBox checkMagne;
    TextView accX;
    TextView accY;
    TextView accZ;
    TextView magneX;
    TextView magneY;
    TextView magneZ;
    TextView gyroX;
    TextView gyroY;
    TextView gyroZ;
    String FILENAME;
    String content1;
    String content2;
    String content3;
    FileOutputStream out;
    Button startButton;
    Button stopButton;
    boolean startFlag = false;
    EditText textData;
    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private boolean running_chronometer;
    boolean isFirstSet = true;
    private long currentTime;
    private long startTime;

    float[] acceleration = new float[3];
    float[] gyroscope = new float[3];
    float[] magnetometer = new float[3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_data);
        // define sensors
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mGyroscope = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        // define text views
        accX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_acc_x);
        accY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_acc_y);
        accZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_acc_z);
        magneX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_magne_x);
        magneY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_magne_y);
        magneZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_magne_z);
        gyroX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_gyro_x);
        gyroY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_gyro_y);
        gyroZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_gyro_z);

        // define checkboxes
        checkAcc=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkGyro=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkMagne=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

        // file name to be entered
        textData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        textData.setHint("Enter File Name here...");

        // define chronometer
        chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        chronometer.setFormat("Recording: %s");
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        // define start button
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_record);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // create file
                FILENAME= textData.getText() + ".csv";
                if(!checkAcc.isChecked() && !checkGyro.isChecked() && !checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please select at least one sensor!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(FILENAME.equals(".csv")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please insert a valid name for the file to be created!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    // set the recording button ON
                    startFlag = true;
                    // make the chronometer run
                    if (!running_chronometer) {
                        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        chronometer.start();
                        running_chronometer = true;
                        checkAcc.setClickable(false);
                        checkGyro.setClickable(false);
                        checkMagne.setClickable(false);
                    }
                    // add screen message to confirm that the app is recording
                    try{
                        textData.getText().clear();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Start recording the data set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // Turn off the record button
                    startButton.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
        }); // starts button ends here

        // define stop button
        stopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // set the recording button OFF
                // Stop writing on file
                startFlag = false;
                isFirstSet = true;
                // if there is no file created state the following message
                if(FILENAME==null || FILENAME.equals(".csv")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no recording taken in this moment!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    // stop the chronometer
                    chronometer.stop();
                    running_chronometer = false;
                    checkAcc.setClickable(true);
                    checkGyro.setClickable(true);
                    checkMagne.setClickable(true);
                    // add screen message to confirm that the app has saved the data set
                    try{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILENAME,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                // Turn back on the Record button
                startButton.setClickable(true);
            }
        });  // stop button ends here
    } // onCreate class ends here

    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // when recording is ON do this
        if (startFlag) {
            if (checkAcc.isChecked() && event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                acceleration[0] = event.values[0];
                acceleration[1] = event.values[1];
                acceleration[2] = event.values[2];
            }

            if (checkGyro.isChecked() && event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                gyroscope[0] = event.values[0];
                gyroscope[1] = event.values[1];
                gyroscope[2] = event.values[2];
            }

            if (checkMagne.isChecked() && event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                magnetometer[0] = event.values[0];
                magnetometer[1] = event.values[1];
                magnetometer[2] = event.values[2];
            }


            // initialise the content that will be written in the file
            if (isFirstSet) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                isFirstSet = false;
            }

            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            content1 = (currentTime - startTime) + "," + "ACC" + "," + acceleration[0] + "," + acceleration[1] + "," + acceleration[2] + "\n";
            content2 = (currentTime - startTime) + "," + "GYR" + "," + gyroscope[0] + "," + gyroscope[1] + "," + gyroscope[2] + "\n";
            content3 = (currentTime - startTime) + "," + "MAG" + "," + magnetometer[0] + "," +magnetometer[1] + "," +  magnetometer[2] + "\n";
            // as long the recording is ON
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                try {
                    // create the file
                    out = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // write to the file
                    if (checkAcc.isChecked() && checkGyro.isChecked() && checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            handler10 = new Handler();
                            runnable10 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler10.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                    updateAccText();
                                    updateGyroText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content1.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content2.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            handler100 = new Handler();
                            runnable100 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler100.postDelayed(this, 100);
                                    updateMagneText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content3.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (checkAcc.isChecked() && checkGyro.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            runnable10 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler10.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                    updateAccText();
                                    updateGyroText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content1.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content2.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (checkAcc.isChecked() && checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            runnable10 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler10.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                    updateAccText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content1.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            runnable100 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler100.postDelayed(this, 100);
                                    updateMagneText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content3.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (checkGyro.isChecked() && checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            runnable10 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler10.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                    updateGyroText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content2.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            runnable100 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler100.postDelayed(this, 100);
                                    updateMagneText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content3.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (checkAcc.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            runnable10 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler10.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                    updateAccText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content1.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (checkGyro.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            runnable10 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler10.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                    updateGyroText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content2.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    } else if (checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                        if (startFlag) {
                            runnable100 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    handler100.postDelayed(this, 100);
                                    updateMagneText();
                                    try {
                                        out.write(content3.getBytes());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    }
            } // for loop end
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    protected void updateAccText(){
        // Update the gyroscope data
        accX.setText(String.format("%.6f", acceleration[0]));
        accY.setText(String.format("%.6f", acceleration[1]));
        accZ.setText(String.format("%.6f", acceleration[2]));
    }

    protected void updateGyroText(){
        // Update the gyroscope data
        gyroX.setText(String.format("%.6f", gyroscope[0]));
        gyroY.setText(String.format("%.6f", gyroscope[1]));
        gyroZ.setText(String.format("%.6f", gyroscope[2]));
    }

    protected void updateMagneText(){
        // Update the gyroscope data
        magneX.setText(String.format("%.6f", magnetometer[0]));
        magneY.setText(String.format("%.6f", magnetometer[1]));
        magneZ.setText(String.format("%.6f", magnetometer[2]));
    }



}
```

When I press the record (start) button, I expect to create a .csv file that saves every single value from each checked (chosen) sensor before it was changed and so on until the user is pressing the save (stop) button.

Answer (score 1):

You create a runnable code block, but never execute it. Call this when you create a runnable and want to set it running:

```
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have managed to do it. 
I save the value for GYR every 5 ms and MAG every 100 ms, and if the saved value is still equal with the new value then wait and write when they are different. I think this is a good example.

I will let the code here, maybe it could help other people:

Java:

```
package localhost.dev.liverpoolsensorsfusion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RecordDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Sensor mGyroscope;
    private Sensor mMagnetometer;
    CheckBox checkAcc;
    CheckBox checkGyro;
    CheckBox checkMagne;
    TextView accX;
    TextView accY;
    TextView accZ;
    TextView magneX;
    TextView magneY;
    TextView magneZ;
    TextView gyroX;
    TextView gyroY;
    TextView gyroZ;
    String FILENAME;
    String content1;
    String content2;
    String content3;
    FileOutputStream out;
    Button startButton;
    Button stopButton;
    boolean isFirstSet = true;
    boolean startFlag = false;
    EditText textData;
    private Chronometer chronometer;
    private boolean running_chronometer;
    private long currentTime;
    private long startTime;

    float[] acceleration = new float[3];
    float[] gyroscope = new float[3];
    float[] magnetometer = new float[3];

    float[] new_gyroscope = new float[3];
    float[] new_magnetometer = new float[3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_data);
        // define sensors
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mGyroscope = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        // define text views
        accX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_acc_x);
        accY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_acc_y);
        accZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_acc_z);
        magneX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_magne_x);
        magneY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_magne_y);
        magneZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_magne_z);
        gyroX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_gyro_x);
        gyroY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_gyro_y);
        gyroZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.raw_value_gyro_z);

        // define checkboxes
        checkAcc=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkGyro=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkMagne=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

        // file name to be entered
        textData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        textData.setHint("Enter File Name here...");

        // define chronometer
        chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        chronometer.setFormat("Recording: %s");
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        // define start button
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_record);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // create file
                FILENAME= textData.getText() + ".csv";
                if(!checkAcc.isChecked() && !checkGyro.isChecked() && !checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please select at least one sensor!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(FILENAME.equals(".csv")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please insert a valid name for the file to be created!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    // set the recording button ON
                    startFlag = true;
                    // make the chronometer run
                    if (!running_chronometer) {
                        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        chronometer.start();
                        running_chronometer = true;
                        checkAcc.setClickable(false);
                        checkGyro.setClickable(false);
                        checkMagne.setClickable(false);
                    }
                    // add screen message to confirm that the app is recording
                    try{
                        textData.getText().clear();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Start recording the data set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // Turn off the record button
                    startButton.setClickable(false);
                }
            }
        }); // starts button ends here

        // define stop button
        stopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // set the recording button OFF
                // Stop writing on file
                startFlag = false;
                // if there is no file created state the following message
                if(FILENAME==null || FILENAME.equals(".csv")){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no recording taken in this moment!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    // stop the chronometer
                    chronometer.stop();
                    running_chronometer = false;
                    checkAcc.setClickable(true);
                    checkGyro.setClickable(true);
                    checkMagne.setClickable(true);
                    // add screen message to confirm that the app has saved the data set
                    try{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILENAME,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                // Turn back on the Record button
                startButton.setClickable(true);
            }
        });  // stop button ends here
    } // onCreate class ends here

    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (startFlag) {
            if (checkAcc.isChecked() && event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                acceleration[0] = event.values[0];
                acceleration[1] = event.values[1];
                acceleration[2] = event.values[2];
            }

            if (checkGyro.isChecked() && event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                gyroscope[0] = event.values[0];
                gyroscope[1] = event.values[1];
                gyroscope[2] = event.values[2];
            }

            if (checkMagne.isChecked() && event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                magnetometer[0] = event.values[0];
                magnetometer[1] = event.values[1];
                magnetometer[2] = event.values[2];
            }
            // when recording is ON do this
            // initialise the content that will be written in the file
            if (isFirstSet) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                isFirstSet = false;
            }
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            content1 = (currentTime-startTime) + "," + "ACC" + "," + acceleration[0] + "," + acceleration[1] + "," + acceleration[2] + "\n";
            content2 = (currentTime-startTime) + "," + "GYR" + "," + gyroscope[0] + "," + gyroscope[1] + "," + gyroscope[2] + "\n";
            content3 = (currentTime-startTime) + "," + "MAG" + "," + magnetometer[0] + "," +magnetometer[1] + "," +  magnetometer[2] + "\n";
            // as long the recording is ON
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                try {
                    // create the file
                    out = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // write to the file
                if (checkAcc.isChecked() && checkGyro.isChecked() && checkMagne.isChecked() && startFlag) {
                    updateAccText();
                    writeAcc();
                    updateGyroText();
                    HandleGyr();
                    if(new_gyroscope[0]==gyroscope[0] && new_gyroscope[1]== gyroscope[1] && new_gyroscope[2]==gyroscope[2]){
                        writeGyr();
                    }
                    updateMagneText();
                    HandleMag();
                    if(new_magnetometer[0]==magnetometer[0] && new_magnetometer[1] == magnetometer[1] && new_magnetometer[1] == magnetometer[1]){
                        writeMag();
                    }
                } else if (checkAcc.isChecked() && checkGyro.isChecked() && startFlag) {
                    updateAccText();
                    updateGyroText();
                    writeAcc();
                    HandleGyr();
                    if(new_gyroscope[0]==gyroscope[0] && new_gyroscope[1]== gyroscope[1] && new_gyroscope[2]==gyroscope[2]){
                        writeGyr();
                    }
                } else if (checkAcc.isChecked() && checkMagne.isChecked() && startFlag) {
                    updateAccText();
                    updateMagneText();
                    writeAcc();
                    HandleMag();
                    if(new_magnetometer[0]==magnetometer[0] && new_magnetometer[1] == magnetometer[1] && new_magnetometer[1] == magnetometer[1]){
                        writeMag();
                    }
                } else if (checkGyro.isChecked() && checkMagne.isChecked() && startFlag) {
                    updateGyroText();
                    updateMagneText();
                    HandleGyr();
                    HandleMag();
                    if(new_gyroscope[0]==gyroscope[0] && new_gyroscope[1]== gyroscope[1] && new_gyroscope[2]==gyroscope[2]){
                        writeGyr();
                    }
                    if(new_magnetometer[0]==magnetometer[0] && new_magnetometer[1] == magnetometer[1] && new_magnetometer[1] == magnetometer[1]){
                        writeMag();
                    }
                } else if (checkAcc.isChecked() && startFlag) {
                    updateAccText();
                    writeAcc();
                } else if (checkGyro.isChecked() && startFlag) {
                    updateGyroText();
                    writeGyr();
                } else if (checkMagne.isChecked()) {
                    updateAccText();
                    writeAcc();
                }
            } // for loop end
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    protected void updateAccText(){
        // Update the gyroscope data
        accX.setText(String.format("%.6f", acceleration[0]));
        accY.setText(String.format("%.6f", acceleration[1]));
        accZ.setText(String.format("%.6f", acceleration[2]));
    }
    protected void updateGyroText(){
        // Update the gyroscope data
        gyroX.setText(String.format("%.6f", gyroscope[0]));
        gyroY.setText(String.format("%.6f", gyroscope[1]));
        gyroZ.setText(String.format("%.6f", gyroscope[2]));
    }
    protected void updateMagneText(){
        // Update the gyroscope data
        magneX.setText(String.format("%.6f", magnetometer[0]));
        magneY.setText(String.format("%.6f", magnetometer[1]));
        magneZ.setText(String.format("%.6f", magnetometer[2]));
    }
    // Adjust sampling rate for Gyroscope
    public void HandleGyr(){
        Handler handlerGyroscope = new Handler();
        handlerGyroscope.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new_gyroscope[0]=gyroscope[0];
                new_gyroscope[1]=gyroscope[1];
                new_gyroscope[2]=gyroscope[2];
            }
        }, 5);
    }
    // Adjust sampling rate for Magnetometer
    public void HandleMag(){
        Handler handlerMagnetometer = new Handler();
        handlerMagnetometer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new_magnetometer[0]=magnetometer[0];
                new_magnetometer[1]=magnetometer[1];
                new_magnetometer[2]=magnetometer[2];
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    public void writeAcc(){
        try {
            out.write(content1.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeGyr(){
        try {
            out.write(content2.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeMag(){
        try {
            out.write(content3.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecordDataActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_acc_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="X:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_acc_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_acc_x"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Y:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_acc_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_acc_y"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Z:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphZ" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_acc_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_acc_x"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_acc_x"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_acc_x"
        android:textColor="@color/graphX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_acc_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_acc_y"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_acc_y"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_acc_y"
        android:textColor="@color/graphY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_acc_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_acc_z"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_acc_z"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_acc_z"
        android:textColor="@color/graphZ" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_gyro_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="X:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_gyro_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_gyro_x"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Y:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_gyro_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_gyro_y"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Z:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphZ" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_gyro_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_gyro_x"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_gyro_x"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_gyro_x"
        android:textColor="@color/graphX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_gyro_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_gyro_y"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_gyro_y"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_gyro_y"
        android:textColor="@color/graphY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_gyro_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_gyro_z"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_gyro_z"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_gyro_z"
        android:textColor="@color/graphZ" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_magne_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="X:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_magne_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_magne_x"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Y:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_label_magne_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_magne_y"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Z:"
        android:textColor="@color/graphZ" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_magne_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_magne_x"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_magne_x"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_magne_x"
        android:textColor="@color/graphX" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_magne_y"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_magne_y"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_magne_y"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_magne_y"
        android:textColor="@color/graphY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/raw_value_magne_z"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/raw_label_magne_z"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/raw_label_magne_z"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/raw_label_magne_z"
        android:textColor="@color/graphZ" />


    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="193dp"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:inputType="" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="126dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_quit"
        android:shadowColor="#8A8A8A"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:text="@string/record"
        android:textColor="#FFF1D6"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="OnClick"
        tools:text="Record" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_stop"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bulb_led"
        android:shadowColor="#8A8A8A"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="#FFF1D6"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="OnClick"
        tools:text="Save" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/accelerometer"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_record"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_acc_z"
        android:text="@string/gyroscope"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/raw_label_gyro_z"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/magnetometer"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```